# Passing args to rails dbconsole

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`rails dbconsole` detects the native DB client and loads it up with all the proper credentials and parameters passed. Is there a way to pass additional parameters to the DB client?

For instance, if you're using mysql, it will load up `mysql` client. I'd like to be able to pass arguments such as `mysql -e 'SELECT NOW();'` or whatever custom query I would like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, what you're asking is not possible. You can pass some options though, check

```
$ rails dbconsole -h
Usage: rails dbconsole [environment] [options]
-p, --include-password           Automatically provide the password from database.yml
    --mode [MODE]                Automatically put the sqlite3 database in the specified mode (html, list, line, column).
    --header
-h, --help                       Show this help message.
-e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment to run this console under (test/development/production).
                                 Default: development
```

Comment: Hopefully this won't be the answer in a few months/years. Looks like I need to submit a PR to the project. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking is not perfectly possible!

```
echo -e "SELECT NOW();\n" | rails dbconsole
```